# Asp.net Report Viewer zoom dropdown missing from the report toolbar

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke, reportviewer

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the web report viewer control version 11.0.  The report toolbar displays, but the zoom dropdown is missing in all browsers.  I understand that zooming is only supported in IE.  I tested in IE9 and IE10.  The zoom dropdown is not there. The dropdown shows in the Visual Studio designer, but not in the browser.  How can I get the zoom to show and work?

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReportRendering"  ShowZoomControl="true"    ZoomMode="PageWidth"  ShowPrintButton="true"   SizeToReportContent="True" runat="server"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ShowBackButton="True" Width="621px" ProcessingMode="Remote"  >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I am using the ReportViewer control in a custom DNN 7.1.1 module.  The ReportViewer control works perfectly in a basic asp.net website.  Has anyone here had any trouble with the ReportViewer and DNN?  I am planning to check with DNN to see if they have seen this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a general software question, rather than a programming one. If so - please try superuser.com instead

Answer (score 0):

After hours of troubleshooting, I tracked the ReportViewer rendering issue to a problem only happening in the professional version of DNN (I'm using Evok Content 7.1.1).  Installing the module in the community version, DNN 7.1.1, works fine.

The problem was 51Degrees.mobi-Premium.dat in App_Data.
When removed, the ReportViewer rendered correctly.  However it kept getting re-generated.

To avoid this, in the web.config, I replaced the professional version with the community version as follows:
Replaced

```
<add name="Detector"  type="DotNetNuke.Provider.Professional.FiftyOnePremiumProvider.DetectModule, DotNetNuke.Provider.Professional.FiftyOnePremiumProvider"  />
```

With

```
<add name="Detector" type="FiftyOne.Foundation.Mobile.Detection.DetectorModule, FiftyOne.Foundation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
```

The Zoom drop down now shows up.